# acceptsReturn set to True for WebControls TextBox

Tags: textbox, web-controls, system.web.ui.webcontrols

How can I impose similar behavior that acceptsReturn = "True" imposes on a  System.Windows.Forms textbox on a System.Web.UI.WebControls textbox? If asp:TextBox cannot have this behavior, i.e., going to the next line when Enter is pressed what is the next simplest control that has this capability?